# Ember.js new router custom slug usage

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am using this router code:

```
Ngin.Router.map(function(match) {
    "use strict";
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.route('article', {path: '/technical/:url/'});
});
```

I need to somehow get the clicked element url in the `serialize` method, so that I can get that article's data from the model. I looks obvious how one should do this in the case of an `id` but I have no clue about how I should do this with a `url`.

Comment: What about overriding router's model method?

Comment: The router model method theoretically replaces the serialize method (though I am not sure about this). But yes, you are right, that is probably the thing  should do. The question is how should that be done in the case of a url route parameter, instead of the default id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always with Ember, the solution is simple. The only thing one needs to get used to, is that Ember is not jQuery, and that context in Ember is (or should be) data, aka models.

```
Ngin.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    serialize: function(model) {
        "use strict";
        return {
            url: model.get("url") + "/"
        };
    }
});
```

And context has to be set like this in this case:

```
{{#linkTo "article" article}}{{article.title}}{{/linkTo}}
```

This is it. As simple as that.

Comment: It looks like someone downvoted this with leaving no comment. I would like to know wha that happened. The answer is still valid, still good.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the route in such way

```
Ngin.Router.map(function(match) {
    "use strict";
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.route('article', {path: '/technical/:url/'});
});

Ngin.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ngin.Article.find({'url': params.url});
  }
});
```

See http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models

Comment: Btw, I'm looking for solution how to extract only one Object, not the ModelArray.

Comment: This was the first thing I read in the documentation, but the model function never gets called.